# Can Thermal Energy be converted into usable energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, energy-conservation

I'm going to go out on a limb and ask a question that will probably be a bit humiliating: Can Thermal Energy be converted into usable energy? I've been reading about conservation of energy, and I know that in no conversion is all the energy usable. There is always some thermal energy (which leads to the conclusion of the inevitable heat death of the universe). But couldn't this problem be avoided by turning the thermal energy into forms of usable energy?

Nothing I've read ever said that thermal energy couldn't be changed back, so why don't we do it? Is it impossible? (Which I find hard to believe). Is it too inefficient? (That would mean that the thermal energy is converted into, well, more thermal energy. Which we can make more usable energy out of. Still more inefficiency? Do it again.) Is there some other reason? Or is there an actual theoretical way to turn thermal energy into usable forms of energy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To turn thermal energy into useful work completely one would need a thermal bath at the temperature of absolute zero. This is explicitly forbidden by the third law of thermodynamics. The best one can do is given by the efficiency of the (theoretical) Carnot cycle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot_cycle. Th efficiency of the Carnot cycle only depends on the ratio of the temperatures of the cold and the hot thermal baths that a cyclical thermodynamic machine has access to:

$\eta= 1 - T_{cold}/T_{hot}$.

As you can see from the formula, if $T_{cold}=0$, then the efficiency would be equal to one, i.e. all thermal energy would be converted. That, as we said, is forbidden, because of $T_{cold}>0$. On the other hand, if $T_{cold} =T_{hot}$, then the efficiency of any thermal machine is zero, i.e. one can't extract any useful energy from just one temperature bath.

Practical efficiencies that can be reached with real thermal machines range up to 60% (in combined cycle natural gas plants, I believe), but it becomes increasingly more expensive to improve efficiencies, so at some point the cost of the improvement is higher than the cost of the lost energy, at which point economics sets a limit to energy efficiency. A better way to use the lost heat is for heating purposes. Combining a small power plant with the heating systems of buildings makes almost 100% use of the energy in the fuels that are being burned in the power plant. These cogeneration facilities (named so because they produce electricity and useful heat) are playing an increasingly larger role in energy efficiency improvements.

Comment: Even still, there is an incredible amount of thermal energy in the universe. You've shown that it is possible, theoretically, to convert almost all the heat in a temperature bath. Then add more heat. If we're using the energy, it'll become more heat to use. You could then say that that little bit of heat energy left each time will accumulate for the eventual heat death. Okay, if it's accumulating, just use it once it becomes enough. So could we theoretically prevent the heat death of the universe as long as we existed to do so?

Comment: Posted that before your edit. But reaching maximum cost-effective efficiency, couldn't we make enough to achieve the same effect as I mentioned?

Comment: The limit is the cold temperature bath. The coldest temperature bath in the universe that exists in virtually "unlimited" quantity is the cosmic microwave radiation, so that's 2.7K, very close to absolute zero. The problem with that is that a radiator at 2.7K is extremely inefficient, so we can't practically make use of that particular thermal bath. On Earth it's technically hard to heat machines higher than to approx. 1200K degrees and to have the cold bath lower than maybe 400K. Real machines will always be less efficient than the Carnot limit... so that's the technical limitation to 60%.

Comment: For theoretical purposes one could add that black holes should have temperatures that are extremely close to 0K, so, at least in theory, a thermodynamic machine converting heat using a black hole as a heat dump should have an efficiency of almost 100%. I do not know if the naive thermodynamic limit is correct for black holes, though.

Comment: Say we placed our observations on just one solar system, and took the unusable thermal energy we produced and converted into as much usable energy as we could, which we use, making excess thermal energy again, although not as much as before. Since there isn't as much as before, obviously the trimmed thermal energy is outside of the system in question. So we take back the thermal energy that had escaped, although not necessarily the same thermal energy, just the same amount, and then the original quantity of energy is back in the system.

Comment: Now imagine we did that with two of these systems. Most of the trimmed energy from one system is deposited in the other system, which then uses it and deposits most of the trimmed energy back in the first one, and so on. Not all of the thermal energy would be conserved, some thrown out of both systems, but we could just bring it back in. Now imagine we did that with all of the universe we could possibly do it for. Nearly all of the energy of that one large system would be conserved within the system, with a minute amount spilling out.

Comment: But by the time all those minute amounts have collected outside of our limits, we'll certainly have advanced the borders of the system. Thus, the heat death of the universe could be prevented for an incredible amount of time. Is this plausible?

Comment: The limit is universal and is given by the cold temperature bath. Like I said, without black holes that's approx. $T_{cold} = 2.7K$. Since the sun has a temperature of $T_{hot} = 5800K$, the limit efficiency for generating useful work from solar radiation would be $\eta=1-2.7K/5800K\approx0.99953$. This idea was put forward by Dyson with his Dyson-sphere surrounding the entire sun. Is this plausible? You decide.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. Not counting the thermal radiation from other bodies in the systems, wouldn't still reaching that limit for as long and as far out as possible prevent the heat-death of the universe more than negligible time?

Comment: Some people have done calculations on that and using brown dwarves one could probably survive in a cold universe for at least hundreds of billions of years. You have to keep in mind that one can stretch "energy reserves" many ways. One is by making the reserve larger, the other is by conserving energy. And once you add tapping into black hole evaporation into the mix, the time scales are going trough the roof (towards 1e100 years, or so!). All of this does assume, of course, that heat death is the limit and not e.g. a big rip or proton decay.

Comment: Of course; this is only theoretically figuring out how long the heat death could be prevented, notwithstanding other factors. So that's pretty interesting. Thanks for the help answering this question! I personally think this is something that should be touched upon in books and articles. I'm sure there are many people asking about converting thermal energy into usable energy, but there are so few answers out there.

Comment: Don't forget the heat capacity of the low-temperature reservoir is also important. Unfortunately it goes to zero as $T$ goes to zero.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible up to the Carnot limit, which is never 100%. In particular, the Carnot limit is higher if the temperature before extracting is higher. But you could only hit 100% if the temperature could reach infinity, which it can't.

Answer (score 0):

There was a time, when trains worked on coal.
What sort of energy, do you think, it was? - Thermal.

There's also solar energy, which is, if you think thoroughly, thermal energy. You turn heat (received by a solar panel) into an usable energy source. However, as I know, solar energy produces so little electricity, it's not worth all the effort.

The way, I see it: if that massive heat energy source (the sun) can't produce energy enough to use it efficiently (I mean, if you don't have extremely large solar panels*), what other sources do you recommend?

> *There are projects somewhere across the globe, when people cover their whole roofs with solar panels and yet they produce about 10% of the energy needed for that house.

Comment: Actually, no, they didn't run on thermal energy. The steps: Coal was burned, which was converted into steam, and the steam turned turbines which ran the train. Solar energy is called Radiant Energy, which is converted into *Electromagnetic* Energy by the cells. The thermal energy is that which is released by the inefficiency, and it's not usable for electricity at all without converting it.

Comment: Well, my apologies...

Comment: Oh, it's no problem. Thank you for putting thought into helping me answer the question! Every raised concern helps to increase the thoroughness.

Answer (score 0):

Thermal energy can convert directly to usable electricity via a thermionic energy convertor (TEC). Heat excites electrons at the surface of a metal, which electrons escape the metal surface (typically a filament) and become free-electrons (Edison Effect). Using vacuum electronics or vacuum semiconductors, these free electrons can form electron beams and power Inductive Output Tubes (IOT), magnetrons, particle amplifiers such as klystrons, and TECs. In the latter case, capturing the electron beam results in capturing the converted energy. Patented in 1915, used by Soviets in spacecraft in the 1960s, low conversion efficiencies (<10%) have militated against commercialization. Recent prototypes at Max Planck Institute and at Space Charge LLC now target conversion efficiencies of 50%.

Answer (score 0):

Only thermal *gradients* can be turned into usable energy. There's a general principle that gradients of physical quantities can be used to drive processes. Take a look at this table$^\dagger$ I took from my lecture notes
[image]

The quantities in the leftmost column are things that can be transported (mass, heat etc.) and the quantities in the top row represent energy gradients that can drive transport. Each entry of this table will generate a transport law of the form
$$J_i=L_{ij}\nabla X_j.$$
Along the diagonal we have for example [Fick's diffusion law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion), which is about transporting mass. Fick's law is given by $J_\phi=-D\nabla \phi$ with $\phi$ the concentration. Also [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law#Other_versions), which is about transporting electrical energy, becomes $J_E=-\sigma\nabla V_E$ with $V_E$ the electric potential such that $E=-\nabla V_E$.

The interesting effects occur at the off-diagonal terms. The [Peltier effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect#Peltier_effect) for example can use electricity to provide cooling (or heating). An interesting result that follows from the second law of thermodynamics is that $L_{ij}$ is symmetric, i.e. $L_{ij}=L_{ji}$. In practice this means that for any of these off-diagonal processes there's some reverse process. If we look at the partner of the Peltier effect we find the Seebeck effect which uses thermal gradients to generate a voltage. So it is essentially the reverse.

$\dagger$ These lecture notes are sadly not publicly available.